# How to set integer and string range from string in Java

Tags: java

The input given is `Integer` + `String`, however I want to set a range of integer input (1~34) and `String` (A~F).
if I do,

```
int i = (Integer.parseInt(input));

if (n > 34) {
    System.out.println("number too high");
}
```

it gives me

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "35A"
```

is there any way to make this work? thanks in advace :(

if the string is 1A to 34F it should pass, anything over that should fail.. please help!

Comment: Is it always one or two digits followed by a letter? Or could it be something like 1A3?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca Its always one or two digits followed by a letter. it cant be 1A3

Comment: What are `1A` and `34F`? Hexadecimal strings or just strings and you have to extract the numbers from them?

Comment: parseInt needs the whole string to be the integer. If you know it is always 1 letter you can do `Integer.parseInt( input.subString(0, input.length() - 1))`

Comment: You have to split the input into the string part and the integer part and test for both conditions (integerPart > 34 11 stringPart > "E") separately.
If the letters can be lowercase, be careful about that.

Comment: @Chaosfire its just a string.

Comment: *The input given is Integer + String, however I want to set a range of integer input (1~34) and String (A~F).* In that case, why are you yoking the two tokens together with the likes of 34F instead of passing the two tokens as two ranges, e.g. `1..34 A..F` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use regex with grouping to easily extract data from the string:

```
public class RandomStuff {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String string = "34F";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\d{1,2})([A-F])");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);
    if (!matcher.find()) {
      System.out.println("does not match pattern, do whatever is needed");
      //stop execution however applicable for use case
    }
    int number = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
    if (number < 1 || number > 34) {
      System.out.println("number not in range");//or other message
    }
    // no need to validate letters
  }
}
```

`(\\d{1,2})` - matches 1 or 2 numbers (0 to 99) and captures it as group 1.

`([A-F])` matches a single letter (A, B, C, D, E or F) and captures result as group 2. If lower case letters are valid as well, you can add a case insensitive flag or add character set for lower letters as well - `[a-f]`, to this group.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to parse a hexadecimal string, pass a radix argument:

`Integer.parseInt(input, 16)`

If it's not hexadecimal, you need to separate the String into the number part and other part first (can't tell you how since you haven't told us what the options are), and then only pass the String containing numbers to `Integer.parseInt`.

Comment: That would parse `1A3` as well, which they say in the comments would not be valid.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca All relevant information should be added to the question

Comment: They did say what the options are, the very first line of the question. How is your example going to limit the range to 34 for the integer part and A-F for the "String" part.

Answer (score 0):

You could first split the String into number and letter

```
String[] split = n.split("(?=[A-Z])");
```

then check if the two parts fit your needs

```
if(Integer.parseInt(split[0]) > 34 || split[1].charAt(0) > 'F') {
    System.out.println("number too high");
}
```

You'd have to check beforehand that your String actually conforms to that pattern but you said in the comments that it's always in that format, so it should work. Also if lowercase letters are possible you have to change the regex and condition or simply call `toUppercase()` on the input String.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the regular expression to solve the problem:

```
 String patternString="(0{0,1}[1-9][A-F])|([1-2]{1}\\d{1}[A-F]{1})|(3{1}[0-4]{1}[A-F]{1})";
    String data[]={"34f","00F","01F","1a","1A","26b"};
    
    for (int i=0;i < data.length;i++){
        System.out.println(data[i]+":"+Pattern.matches(patternString, data[i]));
    }

 //expected result"
 //34f:false
 //00F:false
 //01F:true
 //1a:false
 //1A:true
 //26b:false
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to use regex.

```
boolean result2 = Pattern.matches("[0-3][0-4]?[A-F]", "34A"); // Compiles and matches pattern

System.out.println(result2);
```

This pattern will fulfill your requirement.

Comment: Have you tested the "15A" and "6B"?

Answer (score 0):

Check the last character.And you can catch NumberFormatException when the parseInt gets an exception without last character.

```
    String input = "34F";
    char lastc = input.charAt(input.length()-1);

    if(lastc >= 'A' && lastc <= 'F'){
        try{
            int n = (Integer.parseInt(input.substring(0,input.length()-1)));

            if (n > 34 || n < 1) {
                System.out.println("number not in range");
            }
        } catch(NumberFormatException e1){
            System.err.println("input error.check it.");
        }
    }else{
        System.err.println("input error.check it.");
    }
```